# Вывод данных из таблицы БД Oracle в html таблицу с возможностью редактирования

Tags: php, oracle

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать вывод данных из таблицы БД Oracle в html таблицу с возможностью редактирования.

Что сделал:
workWithOralce.php

```
        //Вывести данные одной таблицы
    public static function getDataTable($table){


        $conn=oci_connect("login","passord","//localhost/orcl.lan");
        if (!$conn) {
            $e = oci_error();
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        //Запрос наименовай столбцов
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * from dba_tab_columns where table_name = ' . '\'' . $table . '\'');
        oci_execute($stid);

        //Запрос всех данных таблицы
        $stip = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * from ' . $table);
        oci_execute($stip);

        $items = array();
        $items2 = array();

        echo "<table class=\"table table-hover table-striped\" border=\"1\">\n";
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
                    $items[] = $row;
        }

        //Получаем нименования столбцов
        $arr = array();
        foreach($items as $item){
            array_push($arr, $item['COLUMN_NAME']);
        }
        //Удаляем повторяющиеся наименования
        $res = array_unique($arr);
        sort($res);
        $len = count($res);
        $arr2 = array();
        $count = 0;
        //Содаем многомерный массив значений
        while ($row2 = oci_fetch_array($stip, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

            //Генерация многомерного массива
            // Длинна массива зависит от длины $res
            for($n = 0; $n < $len; $n++){
                $arr2[$count][$n] = $row2[$res[$n]];
            }
             $count += 1;
        }
        //Выводим зоговлки таблицы
        echo "<table class=\"table table-hover table-condensed\" border='1'>\n";
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($res as $key) {
            echo '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';

        // Тело таблицы
        $len2 = count($arr2);
        for($b = 0; $b < $len2; $b++){
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($arr2[$b] as $value) {
                echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        echo '</table>';

    }
```

Таблица выводится правильно. А вот как реализовать редактирование с последующим сохранением не пойму.

Comment: Ну редактирование с сохранением *html* таблицы это уже на *javascript* реализовывать нужно. Можете поискать плагины для этого готовые. Для *jQuery* должны быть решения.

Comment: Посылаете данные своему скрипту через ajax или отправку формы ввода. А скрипт уже отправляет в базу запросы на insert/update/delete